# Can't fit fork with integrated crown race fully into frame

Tags: fork, crownrace

I got a replacement fork for my new road bike because it had a deep scratch in the steerer tube and the manufacturer adviced to exchange it. Today I got the replacement fork and just wanted to install it. Somehow I can't fully fit the fork into the steerer tube so the integrated crown race fully attaches to the bearing. I'm sure that I didn't forgot a part and am also pretty sure that I don't have to hammer it in there. Is there the slight possibility the diameter of the crown race could be different? There's a sticker on the fork and on the old one it said 5/29. On the new one it's 1/18. I'm honestly confused.

Edit: Tried to remove the lower bearing to slip it on the fork. But unfortunately the manufacturer uses an Acros aheadset where the bearings can't be removed and are not serviceable.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: What does the underside of the head tube look like? I struggle to believe the lower headset bearing is genuinely permanently stuck in there.

Comment: Added a photo of the lower bearing. But if it would fit outside of the frame it should also fit inside the frame or not?

Comment: I was going to say "at least one other person has the same issue"   having found https://www.reddit.com/r/bikewrench/comments/13gl5rk/cant_fit_fork_with_integrated_crown_race_fully/     then realised the photos were identical.   If you do find an answer elsewhere, please do come back and share your findings here as well.

Comment: Yes, I tried to gather as much info as possible. I'll keep you posted. Gonna contact the manufacturer tomorrow

Comment: Just to round off the whole thing. The fork, or more precisely, the whole bike was replaced by the manufacturer. Reason was too much carbon material / thickening in the area of the integrated crown race.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth checking with the supplier that the replacement fork should be a drop-in replacement for the old one.  Given the different part numbers, they might have simply had a picking error at the warehouse, the 101 and 575 numbers.   
Based on the logo, its a **Rose** bike and in 2023 their contact link is https://www.rosebikes.com/services/help-and-contact

I would advise keeping the shipping packaging in case you need to return this fork as well.

Also, avoid making any modifications like filing or sanding.  What you have may be perfectly serviceable in a different frame.

The 1/18 and 5/29 stickers look like american format dates, with C representing a year but not looking like a year.  They're likely dates for when the part was QC'd or went from manufacturing into inventory.  Notice one is clearly on top of the QR sticker so it was added later.  The other one looks nicely butted up beside so either could be first.